# Calling a product attribute programmatically in the product description in Magento

Tags: php, html, magento, product

Didn't see this question asked anywhere, so here goes:

I have several attributes in my Magento store, but to spare the user from an overly cluttered page, I've separated different kind of information on the product pages with tabs. The first tab displays the product description which currently is a bunch of HTML which basically mirrors the attributes by displaying easy-to-understand icons with the attribute value beneath them and the second tab displays more in-depth information with the attributes called from the DB.

Right now, when editing or adding a product, I will basically have to add the attribute twice: once as an actual product attribute and once for the simple HTML product description with icons.

What I would like to do instead, is to call the attribute programmatically and insert a variable that would load the attribute value under the icon automatically, thus sparing me hours in manually editing and double-checking every value.

A basic line of sample code without some other things currently looks like this:

```
<img src="http://myurl.com/img/profile.jpg" alt="attribute_1_image" /><br /> 70mm
```

Instead of writing out the 70mm manually, I'd like to be able to call it from the database, so I could simply copy and paste the same HTML on every product description page, since I already have 70mm added as attribute_1, so the preferred outcome would be:

```
<img src="http://myurl.com/img/profile.jpg" alt="attribute_1_image" /><br />{var.attribute_1}
```

This, or anything similar where it would simply load the attribute from the same product page the user is currently on.

The closest thing I've come to, is this: http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-attributes-value/ but I realize this can't be done via PHP since the editor will not support it, so I'm stumped as to how I could achieve this. I'm running Magento 1.6.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your custom "variable" as a text replace. Put `{var.attribute_1}` in the description from the backend. Then, in product view, do a string replace.

File `app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.html`:

```
$description = $_product->getDescription();

if ($_product->getVariable1()):
    $description = str_replace(
        '{var.attribute_1}',  
        $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('variable_1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product),
        $description);
endif;
```

and so on for each attribute, then `echo $description;`. You have to *enable the attribute for product view* in Magento backend. No extension needed.

This makes sense only if you have different description "patterns" for your products. Otherwise (for example if variable1 is always present) you can just put your `<img>` tag in this file followed by the attribute value, and keep the description field for an actual description.

**Edit**: to prevent {var.attribute_1} to be shown in the product view even while the actual attribute is empty, the following code looks better:

```
$description = $_product->getDescription();

$attribute_value = 
         ($_product->getVariable1()) ? 
          $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('variable_1')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) 
          : "";
$description = str_replace(
      '{var.attribute_1}',  
      $attribute_value,
       $description);
```

Comment: Edited, I'll try this out once I'm back home. But by variable, did you mean attribute, just to be sure?

I don't really want to hardcode the description since they do have different patterns, some products have more icons than others, some need to open a lightbox when clicked on, etc, so they vary.

I'll be back home in a few hours, so I'll give that a go and see what happens. Thanks for now!

Comment: Just to be clear, `variable_1` is the attribute's name (the code name, not the attribute label). Magento can get the attribute through the quick call "getVariable1()", based on the name's format.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I either did it wrong or it didn't work. I added the code you wrote in the view.phtml file and echoed $description in every possible place with no results. My code looked like this: http://pastebin.com/V0HuuQLe (sorry, I couldn't format the code in the comments for some reason)


The text I replaced was then {var.thickness} and the attribute's code simply thickness. Not sure what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @Cardo There are 2 errors: http://pastebin.com/diff.php?i=tWfAtQmv
If you put `echo $description;` just after the definition `$description = $_product->getDescription();` and it doesn't work, maybe you have the text in `$_product->getShortDescription();` instead, or `$_product` hasn't been defined in that file yet. Please paste the whole file.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted broken code after I had tried to mess around with it and tried different variations. The getAttribute('{var.thickness}') wasn't actually there for more than a a minute, no idea why I even tried that. The whole file currently looks like this: http://pastebin.com/gVKwJhWV


Here's an image how it looks, as well: http://i.imgur.com/E9R9oDf.jpg

Comment: It is not clear if the image is Description or ShortDescription. Other possibilities: description attribute is not enabled for product view (backend) or the template file is not the right one. Anything else looks right.

Comment: It's in the description, I have a completely different thing in the short description and the attribute is enabled from the backend: http://imgur.com/6XdThGc

I'm also quite sure the template file is correct since every other change I've made in it, works, so I'm stumped.

Comment: So `echo` is acting, and replace is not. That should be due to the if condition. Try to use the second snipped I put in the answer to see if the text in the curly brackets is replaced (to nothing) or not.

Comment: The second snippet worked like this! http://pastebin.com/94QVmcYF

It's replaced the text in curly brackets and showed the attribute value immediately after I used this. Thanks a ton!

By the way, what would be the best way to streamline this for about 20 more attributes? Can I enter more values in the same block of PHP or do I need to copy-paste the entire thing as many times as I have attributes that need replacing?

Comment: PS! I still can't seem to replicate this behaviour for other attributes in any way, the text in the curly brackets remains for the second attribute I'm trying to insert via str_replace.

Comment: Just look for typos and echo at the end of all. If you have more than 1 you have to do it one by one

Comment: I solved it another way entirely, your method called for two separate description areas on the same page since I was using an extension called Easy Tabs that also called it, otherwise, it would have worked fine on a vanilla installation of Magento.

I used arrays to put them all into one code, if anyone else might be interested in the future, this is what it looks like now and it's working fine (I also added measurement units to the attributes so they'd be sortable, so there's a bit more): http://pastebin.com/X2Eu06Rm

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to aswer that, but i'm unsure product attribute can be directly inserted in the description field of a product (if that's you wanna do?)

The good way is to have a block on description page and do the layout in there. With html and php like the link you pointed.
After you just have to display this block on the product page and it will load and display attributes for all our products.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thought of this, but then I'd have to create just as many static blocks as I have products, since they're not identical by layout, some product views have more icons than others and need to link to some different images in a lightbox, so I'd be creating endless static blocks. This might be a bit faster than manually editing everything, but Thundar's suggestion about text replace might work better.